# Best preworkout and post workout supplement to help body recover immediately

Tags: workout, bodybuilding, cardio, supplements

I am doing weighlifting for 5 days and 1 day is for cardio but i also do abs workout on my shoulder day.

Problem is when i do cardio then i am not able to do with my full strength i.e i get tired bit early after running for 
15 minutes on treadmill and then cycling for some 10 minutes,leg raise and plank etc.

Other than this problem is i dont think so i am providing enough protein to my body and because of that i am not seeing th result which i want to see.

I also want to do body building and cardio with full strength and i have heard that black coffee before workout can keep me energised but the problem is drinking black coffee on empty stomach have have a bad result on my stomach when i researched about that.

So i have to stop that.

When i wake up i dont feel that refreshed and a feel bit of laziness which in turn affect my workout.

So i decided that may be i should start taking prework out and post workput supplements to help my body immediately recover.

So which standard preworkout and post workout supplements i should opt for which can really help me to get a good aesthetic body which i want?

Comment: Define "immediately recover". That sounds impossible. If it were possible, we'd never ever be tired or sick.

Comment: @Alec:But i have heard and read that prework out and post workout supplements help immediately recover our body as they start repairing out muscles when taken

Comment: That's what the people selling them say anyways. How long have you been doing this?

Comment: @Raditz_35 Sorry but doint what?

Comment: Muscle repair is never an instantaneous process. *SOME TIMES* we take post-workout, but this should never be the first step you take. The best option is to eat the correct food after the gym, and use supplements only when strictly necessary.

Comment: Can you please recommend me some best food for preworkout and post workout which you are taking please

Comment: @Alec - any research to support this?

Comment: @Mike-DHSc - To support which claim? That muscle repair is not instantaneous?

Comment: LOL, you really thought I was asking if there's a time component to recovery??  "SOME TIMES we take post-workout, but this should never be the first step you take. The best option is to eat the correct food after the gym, and use supplements only when strictly necessary."

Comment: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/3217/7091

Answer (score 1):

**Pre Workout:**

- Whey Protein (~25-40g)
- Complex Carbs (Fiber Based Foods i.e Whole Wheat Bread / Fruits etc.)

---

**Post Workout:**

- Whey Protein (~25-40g)
- Simple Sugars (i.e. White Bread, Table Sugar, Honey)

---

### Rationale:

***Whey Protein*** as it's one of the fastest digesting proteins

- Studies have shown increased hypertrophy (muscle growth) by stacking
  these pre and post workout.

***Fructose***  as fructose has different carriers than glucose, delivery of protein and therefore recovery and muscle growth has shown to increase when taken as part of a post workout drink.

**Sucrose** - Simple sugars as your muscles are starving - refined sugars post workout spike your insulin allowing maximum delivery of protein.

**Water** - to help deliver it all.

---

Source:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3529694/

Comment: What should be the duration for hittiing the gym after having prework out foods i.e complex carbs food?

Comment: ~30 min as you'll obviously need energy to complete your workout, the fiber will help slow digestion.

Comment: So what fruits do you recommend for prework out and post workout?

Comment: Any complex carb based source of energy - Fruits are just one of many options.   Literally any raw fruit (just do not juice them as this strips them of their valuable micronutrients and fiber)

Comment: Ok thank you so much for your kind help.Any recommendation on whey protein preworkout and post workout supplements like which brands to take?

Comment: iON you can grab at GNC, personally I use http://www.americanpurewhey.com/whey-isolate-01.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68321/discussion-between-learning-and-mike-dhsc).

Comment: @Mike-DHSc how much simple carbs comparing with protein should be consumed? wouldn't it cause any fat producton in this case?